# JavaScript RegExp.test() returns false, even though it should return true

Tags: javascript, html, regex, jquery

The Prob: I get an AJAX response (JSON or plaintext with line breaks). Each item of the response should be checked via RegEx to find out whether it matches to user-definded patter or not.

Example:

Ajax Response (plain-text)

```
"Aldor
Aleph
Algae
Algo
Algol
Alma-0
Alphard
Altran"
```

User-pattern:

```
/^Alg/ig.test(responseItem)
```

RegExp Results should look like:

```
Aldor   // false
Aleph   // false
Algae   // true
Algo    // true
Algol   // true
Alma-0  // false
Alphard // false
Altran  // false
```

But each time i get different (and kinda weired) results... e.g. (`/^alg/ig.test("Algo")` => **false**)

My code:

**HTML**

```
...
<form>
  <input id="in" />
</form>
<div id="x">
  Aldor
  Aleph
  Algae
  Algo
  Algol
  Alma-0
  Alphard
  Altran
</div><button id="checker">check!</button>
...
```

**JavaScript (jQuery 1.6.2)**

```
$(function(){
    var $checker = $('#checker');

    $checker.click(function(ev){
        var inputFieldVal = $.trim($('#in').val());
        console.log(inputFieldVal); // Alg
        var regExpPattern = '^'+inputFieldVal,
            re = new RegExp(regExpPattern, 'igm');
        onsole.log(re); // /^Al/gim
        // Get text out of div#x
        var text = $('#x').text();
        // Trim and 'convert' to an array...
            text = $.trim(text).split('\n');
        console.log(text); // ["Aldor", "Aleph", "Algae", "Algo", "Algol", "Alma-0", "Alphard", "Altran"]

        for (var index=0, upper=text.length;index<upper;++index) {
            console.log(
               re.test(text[index]),
               text[index]
             );
        }
    });
})
```

**Console OUTPUT:**

`/^Alg/ig` => should match each item which starts with `Alg`

```
false "Aldor"
false "Aleph"
true "Algae"
false "Algo" //Why ? O.o
true "Algol"
false "Alma-0"
false "Alphard"
false "Altran"
```

`/^Al/ig` => should match each item because every item start with `Al`

```
true "Aldor"
false "Aleph" //Why ? O.o
true "Algae"
false "Algo" //Why ? O.o
true "Algol"
false "Alma-0" //Why ? O.o
true "Alphard"
false "Altran" //Why ? O.o
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does executing `/^alg/ig.test("Algo")` literally also give you `false`?

Comment: P.S. The point of whole ting is that I want not only match item(s) from the response, but also be able to collect them.

Comment: @pimvdb, no. `/^alg/ig.test("Algo")` returns true

Comment: Could you please post the result of `text` if you map it first with this function? `text = text.map(function(v) {var res = [];for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++){res.push(v.charCodeAt(i))}return res;})` It converts the string array to their respective character codes, to highlight non-printable characters.

Comment: Trying printing the length of the strings too, in case, somehow, there are 'invisible' characters.

Comment: pimvdb and MRAB: See the screen (http://www.imagebanana.com/view/wd4okkdd/31072011214030.png)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is a common behavior that the the exec or test methods show when you deal with patterns that have the global `g` flag.

The `RegExp` object will keep track of the `lastIndex` where a match was found, and then on subsequent matches it will start from that `lastIndex` instead of starting from `0`.

For example:

```
var re = /^a/g;
console.log(re.test("ab")); // true, lastIndex was 0
console.log(re.test("ab")); // false, lastIndex was 1
```

Remove the `g` flag from your pattern, since you are looking just for a single match (you are testing each line separately).

Comment: What about 3rd execution? why is it again `true`?

Comment: @gumkins, because after reaching the end of the string, the `lastIndex` starts again from `0`.

Comment: still not clear, why the end of the string was reached after second run and not after third or fourth?

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the global flag "g".

Answer (score 0):

try this~

```
var str = "Aldor\rAleph\rAlgae\rAlgo\rAlgol";
var myregexp = /^alg.*$/img;
var match = myregexp.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        alert(match[i]);
    }
    match = myregexp.exec(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it Was the white space that was not matching it:

try this:

```
$(function(){
var $checker = $('#checker');

$checker.click(function(ev){
    var inputFieldVal = $.trim($('#in').val());
    console.log(inputFieldVal); // Alg
    var regExpPattern = '^'+inputFieldVal,
        re = new RegExp(regExpPattern, 'igm');
    console.log(re); // /^Al/gim
    // Get text out of div#x
    var text = $('#x').text();
    // Trim and 'convert' to an array...
        text = $.trim(text).split('\n');
    console.log(text); // ["Aldor", "Aleph", "Algae", "Algo", "Algol", "Alma-0", "Alphard", "Altran"]

    for (var index=0, upper=text.length;index<upper;++index) {
        console.log(
           re.test(text[index].trim()),
           text[index]
         );
    }
});
```

})

here is jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Gqw2/

Comment: It seems to have the same weird-prob as my script. I just tested your version an get the same result....